# Facebook FB.ui dialog iOS Web App unclosable

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, iphone-web-app

I have FB.ui working well, I can share whatever info I need to share. However the issue is that it's being rolled into a Web App (This "add to home screen") for an ipad. Whenever the dialog opens, it's opened full screen, and once it's shared there is no way to close the opened dialog.

```
<input type="button" onclick="share_prompt()" value="Share" />
function share_prompt()
{


FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     display: "iframe",
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
 }
```

I've changed the "display" property to everything possible, but the docs say that it defaults to a "touch" display in web apps.

Also, to make it even more frustrating, the response doesn't fire when in web app mode. Only in the browser window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved this:

```
  if(navigator.standalone){
    new_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?'+
                'app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX'+
                '&display=popup'+
                '&caption='+fbName+
                '&picture='+fbPicture+
                '&description='+fbDescription+
                '&link='+fbLink+
                '&redirect_uri=http://myurl.com/mycontroller/#post_id';

        window.open(new_url,'_self');
  } else {
  //do the normal way
  }
```

This way you can have a redirect url and you can send the post id back to your app if you need it. Hope this answers your question if you still didn't find a way to solve it.